# How do I convolve() more than two distributions without doubling the result rowcount every time?

Tags: r, convolution

I am attempting to `convolve()` 36 beta distributions. The result distribution is one of the two input distributions to the next successive call to `convolve()`. After every `convolve()`, the result has row count = `(nrow(vector1)+nrow(vector2)-1)`. In effect, the row count of the result distribution almost doubles with every call to `convolve()`. This is very inefficient - it makes runtime impossibly long and consumes large amounts of memory. Is there any way to keep the row count constant?

Code example below ...

```
# Function from https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-July/168762.html
weighted.var <- function(x, w, na.rm = FALSE) {
  if (na.rm) {
    w <- w[i <- !is.na(x)]
    x <- x[i]
  }
  sum.w <- sum(w)
  sum.w2 <- sum(w^2)
  mean.w <- sum(x * w) / sum(w)
  (sum.w / (sum.w^2 - sum.w2)) * sum(w * (x - mean.w)^2, na.rm = na.rm);
}

# Define beta distribution shape parameters.
s1a <- 3.52; s1b <- 65.35;
s2a <- 1.684; s2b <- 189.12;
s3a <- 5.696; s3b <- 32.34;
s4a <- 1.81; s4b <- 185.5;

# Define intial set of quantiles.
mQ1 <- matrix(data=seq(0,1,1/1000),ncol=1);

for (i in 1:3){
  mPDF <- matrix(data=convolve(dbeta(mQ1,s1a,s1b),rev(dbeta(mQ1,s2a,s2b)),type="open"),ncol=1L);
  print(paste(nrow(mPDF),' rows',sep=''));

  if(i < 3){
    # Calculate the merged shape parameters directly from mPDF.
    mQ2 <- matrix(data=seq(0,1L,(1L/(nrow(mPDF)-1L))),ncol=1L);
    wtMean <- weighted.mean(mQ2,mPDF);
    wtStd <- sqrt(weighted.var(mQ2,mPDF));
    s1a <- -1L * ((wtMean*(wtStd^2 + wtMean^2 - wtMean))/wtStd^2);
    s1b <- ((wtStd^2 + wtMean^2 - wtMean)*(wtMean - 1))/wtStd^2;

    s2a <- s3a; s2b <- s3b;
    mQ1 <- mQ2;
  }

} #i
```

Comment: would using `type="filter"` rather than `type="open"` do what you want ... ?

Comment: Hi thanks, but no it does not seem to - "filter" produces a single row containing the weighted mean of the two matrices as far as I can see. Am now instead trying to sample every 2nd record to circumvent this problem (i.e. to keep the row count constant), but this then causes the convolve() operations to lose their commutativity. Will update the post if and when I manage to get it working!